# Visual Studio command prompt error

Tags: command-prompt

When i try to execute this command i am getting this error m

```
C:\>Windows/system32>cd \demos\host\EvalServiceLibrary
'Windows\system32' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed in a prompt yourself.  That won’t work.  Strip the prompt:

```
C:\> cd \demos\host\EvalServiceLibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy to see what are commands and what are results unless you format them. I've fixed the formatting as far as I can tell. Regrettably, it's very difficult to ascertain precisely what you've actally typed - it's critical that we know **exactly** what happened - character-for-character. You've mistyped your question title, there's a stray `m` in your description, so I have some doubts about the accuracy of the remainder.

What really stands out is that in Windows, `/` is a switch-indicator and `\` is a directory-separator. If your command actually is

```
Windows/system32>cd \demos\host\EvalServiceLibrary
```

then you are attempting to execute `windows` with a switch `system32` and redirect the output to `cd`. I'm not suprised `cmd`'s response was `Que?`

Comment: Since there’s no space between `Windows` and `/system32`, the `/` is interpreted as a path separator, not the start of a switch. As such, it’s trying to execute `Windows\system32` (which still makes no sense), not `Windows` with a `/system32` switch, and the error reflects this.